# Free software to compare two 3D models

Tags: windows, linux, 3d, cad

I'm looking for a piece of software for Windows or Linux that can compare how two 3D models differ.

It should preferebly be lightweight piece of free software, but I'm in hearing other options.

Answer (score 1):

CloudCompare seems to be a good choice to do the compare.

[image: (ScreenShot)] With Nice Color range indicate areas been changed and how much are changed

I manage to use Autohotkey to automate the process and post the detailed setup in CloudCompare official forum:

Use CloudCompare as Git diff tool to check model difference - CloudCompare forum http://www.cloudcompare.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=4969